# error open prefrence Could not find folder 'tools...le-windows-x86\sdk\tools\'. in android sdk?

Tags: android, kindle-fire

when i start eclipse it gives error

```
<"Location of the android sdk not has been step in the preference">
```

after that when i click on open `preference` button is ask for `preference` path...

```
<Could not find folder 'tools...le-windows-x86\sdk\tools\'.>
```

plz help me m stuck in this

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you downloaded the Android sdk, I recommend using the [ADT plugin](http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) from developer.android.
Now, in eclipse, in the Menu bar, click on `Window` > `Preferences` then click on `Android`, and on the right pane under `SDK location` make sure you enter the right path for the sdk.

Comment: you are right but i download all the levels and tools now its giving this error ..i want to resolve this problem ..is there any solution for it ..and thanx for your responce